# Informações ficam fora da tabela em while

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql, table

Somente a primeira informação do `tbody` é apresentada as outras aparecem porém em linhas fora da tabela. O que pode estar fazendo isso acontecer?

segue abaixo o trecho do código:

```html
 <?php
  }
  }else {
  $sqle = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM jsondados WHERE empresa='cnet' ");
  $numRegistross = mysqli_num_rows($sqle);
 if ($numRegistross != 0) {
  ?>

<div class="tablediv">
<table class="tablestyle">
<thead>
<tr>
<th class="tabletrstyle">Info1</th>
<th class="tabletrstyle">Info2</th>
<th class="tabletrstyle">Info3</th>
<th class="tabletrstyle">Info4</th>
<th class="tabletrstyle">Info5</th>
<th class="tabletrstyle">Info6</th>
<th class="tabletrstyle">Info7</th>
<th class="tabletrstyle">Info8</th>
</tr>
</thead>


  <?php
  while ($qstr= mysqli_fetch_object($sqle)) {
  ?>


<tbody>
<tr>
<th><?=$qstr->Info1?></th>
<th><?=$qstr->Info2?></th>
<th><?=$qstr->Info3?></th>
<th><?=$qstr->Info4?></th>
<th><?=$qstr->Info5?></th>
<th><?=$qstr->Info6?></th>

</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

Comment: Onde está o final do while ?

Answer (score 1):

O Correto não seria assim?

```
<?php
        }
  }else {
  $sqle = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM jsondados WHERE empresa='cnet' ");
  $numRegistross = mysqli_num_rows($sqle);
    if ($numRegistross != 0) {
  ?>

<div class="tablediv">
<table class="tablestyle">
<thead>
<tr>
<th class="tabletrstyle">Info1</th>
<th class="tabletrstyle">Info2</th>
<th class="tabletrstyle">Info3</th>
<th class="tabletrstyle">Info4</th>
<th class="tabletrstyle">Info5</th>
<th class="tabletrstyle">Info6</th>
<th class="tabletrstyle">Info7</th>
<th class="tabletrstyle">Info8</th>
</tr>
</thead>

<tbody>
<?php
  while ($qstr= mysqli_fetch_object($sqle)) {
?>
<tr>
<th><?=$qstr->Info1?></th>
<th><?=$qstr->Info2?></th>
<th><?=$qstr->Info3?></th>
<th><?=$qstr->Info4?></th>
<th><?=$qstr->Info5?></th>
<th><?=$qstr->Info6?></th>
</tr>
<?php 
  } 
?>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

Comment: Opa, erro bobo, estava deixando para fechar depois do </table>, obrigado. Falta de atenção minha.